# How do I keep a list item in active state after a sort?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view in single choice mode. The list items use:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

Let's say, for example, that I want the third item highlighted. So I do:

```
listView.setItemChecked(2, true);
```

And then let's say I want to move the second item to the first slot:

```
items.add(0, items.remove(1));
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The original third item is now styled as unchecked.

Calling `listView.setItemChecked(2, true)` at any point seems to do nothing. In fact, the third item is still marked as checked, it just isn't styled that way. How do I keep this third item highlighted after sorting the data?